# Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.String' to type 'ImageSource'

Tags: xaml, windows-8

**This is for my Windows 8 app:**

In my object I have a string property that contains the path of the images I want to use.

```
public String ImagePath
```

In my XAML I have set up an Image tag with the following binding:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Margin="50"/>
```

When I reference an image that I've included in my project (in the Asset folder) the image displays correctly.  The path is: `Assets/car2.png`

However, when I reference an image that the user selects (using the FilePicker) I get an error (**and no image**). The path is: `C:\Users\Jeff\Pictures\myImage.PNG`

> Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.String'
>   to type 'ImageSource'

Just to add a little more info.  When I use the file picker I am converting the file location to a URI:

```
        Uri uriAddress =  new Uri(file.Path.ToString());
        _VM.vehicleSingle.ImagePath = uriAddress.LocalPath;
```

**Update:**

I'm also saving this image path to isolated storage.  I think this is where the issue is.  I'm able to save the path of the file selected, but when I try to bind to it when I'm reloading the Isolated Storage it doesn't work.

So if I can't use an image outside of the application directory.  Is there a way I can save that image and add it to the directory?

I tried creating a BitmapImage property to my model but now I'm getting errors stating that it can't serialize a BitmapImage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should Use Converter

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])value,false);
            BitmapImage empImage = new BitmapImage();
            empImage.SetSource(memStream);
            return empImage;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to encapsulate the `MemoryStream` into a `using` clause or dispose the `MemoryStream` if you don't want memory leaks...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a file path that points outside the app directory. You will need to read in the StorageFile stream that you get from the file picker and assign that stream to an image source - so binding is pretty hard unless you change your model,to have an imagesource property instead.

Comment: When I added an imagesource property to my model I got the following error when trying to deserialize my XML in IsoloatedStorage: Cannot serialize member 'autoGarage2.vehicle.myImage' of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource', see inner exception for more details. -- Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you cannot use bindings to access the file system directly, even if you grant access via the File Picker.  Take a look at the [XAML Images Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9) at the [Dev Center](http://dev.windows.com), for a technique you can use.

In a nutshell, you'll use [SetSourceAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsourceasync) to get your file into a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage) and then you can use that as the binding source.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did some work on binding to an ImageSource.

```
public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource PhotoImageSource
{
    get
    {
         if (Photo != null)
         {
              System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage image = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
              image.BeginInit();                    
              image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(Photo);
              image.EndInit();

              return image as System.Windows.Media.ImageSource;
          }
          else
          {
               return null;
          }
     }
}
```

My "Photo" was an image stored in a byte[].  You could either convert your image to a byte[] or maybe try using a FileStream instead (I haven't tested with a FileStream so I can't say if it will work).